# Python: Faster to use global variable or pass as arguments to a function?

Tags: python, functions, variables

Hey so i was wondering which is the more efficient way, or better practice to do in this situation.

1,

```
def function():
    global number
    number += 2
```

Or 2,

```
def function(number):
    return number += 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching? Searching for "python local global performance" turned up [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590058/python-performance-with-global-variables-vs-local) as the first result. More importantly, mutable global variables are a bad idea.

Comment: If you are working on something where the performance difference between a global and a local matters, you should probably not be using python in the first place.  This is a micro-optimization at best, and python's reasons for existence don't include speed.

Answer (score 4):

Performance is irrelevant. Globals are evil (as gnat mentioned); you are best off forgetting the `global` keyword exists. There is always a better way.

Comment: Feels a bit extreme to say "performance is irrelevant"... also you mention there is a better way, but you don't mention or point to it, so it is not a very useful answer IMHO.